# $f$ integrable iff set of discontinuities have measure $0$. But why is $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ not integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, continuity, riemann-integration

I have a theorem stating that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure 0. Using this you can prove that the Thomae function is Riemann integrable. However I'm confused about this function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1  & \text{ if $x$ is rational }  \\    0 & \text{ if $x$ is irrational}   \end{cases}$$

I know that this function is in theory not integrable on $[0,1]$; however, isn't its set of discontinuities $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, which have measure $0$? I'm very confused because the theorem seems to tell me that this function is integrable, while the argument with lower and upper sums of partitions clearly states that it is not.
I hope someone can resolve my confusion.

Comment: It’s discontinuous everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is discontinuous everywhere, because of the density of the rationals and irrationals within $\mathbb{R}$.

Take $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f$ were continuous at $q$, then we could find $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
0 < |x-q| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(q)|=|f(x)-1|<\varepsilon
$$
However, for $\varepsilon = 1/2$ and any $\delta > 0$, we have infinitely many irrationals in $(q-\delta,q+\delta)$, at which $f$ is $0$, and so $|f(x)-f(q)|=1 \not < 1/2$.

Hence, $f$ is discontinuous on the rationals.

A parallel argument follows for the irrationals. Take $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\forall \delta > 0$, we can find $x$ such that
$$
0 < |x-r| < \delta \text{ but } | f(x) - f(r) | = |f(x)| < \frac 1 2
$$
Namely, this occurs when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$; the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ ensures that $(r-\delta,r+\delta)$ has infinitely many rationals for any $\delta > 0$.

Hence, $f$ is discontinuous on the irrationals too.

---

It's easy to think of "well, this function is zero everywhere, except where it jumps up at the irrationals" and go "well, it's discontinuous on a set of measure zero."

However, I think the key realization is that it "jumps up **and down**" *far too often*. In any interval, you can think of the function as oscillating up and down infinitely many times (though in a discontinuous way, unlike $\sin(1/x)$ as an example).

Alternatively, the realization is simply that just because $f=g$ a.e., doesn't mean that the points of (dis)continuity of $f$ or $g$ have no effect. The nature of those points matters too. After all,

- $f := \chi_{\mathbb{Z}}$ has (countably) infinitely-many discontinuities, but integrating it is totally fine, because the integers are sufficiently spread apart
- $f := \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ has (countably) infinitely-many discontinuities, but integrating it (in the Riemann sense) is not fine, since it is discontinuous everywhere

...and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment this makes a lot of sense! So now thinking about the thomae function. The proof that its integrable is to show that there are finitely many $x\in [0,1]$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ but $f(x)-f(x_0)>\epsilon$? So basically the set of discontinuities is finite?

Comment: The set of discontinuities for Thomae's function is $\mathbb{Q}$ (or its intersection with $[0,1]$ if you're viewing it in that sense). Hence the discontinuities are infinite in number, but still of measure zero. [Wikipedia has a proof.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)